# Symfony3 - Repeated FieldType not rendering

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have a repeated fieldtype that is not being rendered when I access the page.
I have this method in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{token}", name="pass_reset_form")
 * 
 * Function to reset password.
 */
public function ResetAction(Request $reset, $token)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ResetformType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($reset);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Logins')->findByToken($token);
        if (!empty($user))
        {
            // encode password and update in the DB
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->encodePassword($user[0], $form["newPassword"]->getData());
            $user[0]->setPassword($password);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'The password has been successfully reset. You can now login.');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login_route');
        }
    }
    return $this->render(
        'VendorMyBundle:Default:resetEntry.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
            );
}
```

and this is the ResetformType:

```
namespace Vendor\MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

class ResetformType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('newPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ));
    }
}
```

and this is the standard twig code:

```
{% block body1 %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Whenever I access the route that takes me on that rendered view I only see the form button. I view page source and all that is in HTML is the form button and a hidden form token field.

```
<form name="resetform" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="resetform__token" name="resetform[_token]" value="2NJ7Uht8bgVUV27GnD4FHrCOjTFCIXXQyraJkG4jSmc" />
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried any other fields to see if those also don't work?  have you tried rendering the field manually with `{{ form_row(form.newPassword) }}`?

Comment: @JasonRoman lol, how weird is that?! It worked. Why didn't it work with the standard form display twig block?

Comment: i would try clearing your cache and then trying with your original method...`form_end(form)` should have automatically put that field in for you since you didn't specify `render_rest` to be false

Comment: Yes, clearing the cache also fixed it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Answering for anybody who bumps into the same issue. 
Either clear your cache or specifically render fields separately, in my case with: 
`{{ form_row(form.newPassword) }}`.